# Need Help-Windows service or other

Tags: windows-services

I have to develop a application in .net technology which calls an external service which returns some data which will be stored on server.

Now this application should run weekly or monthly basis and will also log the success or failure of bath. For logging i dont have to use databse.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that having an application that is run on schedule using windows task scheduler service would be more resource-effective than having your own service that hangs around for weeks just waiting for time to do the job.

More info:

[About Task Scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Scheduler)

[Task scheduler API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383614.aspx)

Comment: hi..is this possible to configure a windows service with windows task scheduler which will start this at desired interval.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include links, which will answer your question as well as other questions that might appear in regards to task scheduler. Please remember to mark the accepted answers to let other people know that the answer is present.